# Dozer collection field not excluded

Tags: java, hibernate, dozer

I'm using Dozer to map my entities to my DTO's
My problem is on an entity with collections lazy loaded. I use a mapping to tell to Dozer to exclude the collections fields to avoid a Lazy Loading exception.
Even with this specific mapping Dozer seems to try to map the collections and then Hibernate throws the Lazy Loading exception...

Here is my specific mapping:

```
 <mapping map-id="employe_simple">
    <class-a>ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.entity.AbstractEmployeEntity</class-a>
    <class-b>ch.tupperware.tuppergestion.dto.AbstractEmployeDto</class-b>
    <field-exclude>
      <a>listeClients</a> 
      <b>listeClients</b> 
    </field-exclude>   
    <field-exclude>
      <a>reunions</a> 
      <b>reunions</b> 
    </field-exclude>   
    <field-exclude>
      <a>responsable</a> 
      <b>responsable</b> 
    </field-exclude>   
  </mapping>
```

Here is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@org.hibernate.annotations.DiscriminatorFormula(value="TYPE_PERSONNE")
@Table(name="EMPLOYE")
public class AbstractEmployeEntity implements UserDetails, Comparable<AbstractEmployeEntity> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3577478107563521474L;

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)  
    @Column(name = "ID_EMPLOYE") 
    private Long id;

    @Column(name= "NOM")
    private String nom;

    @Column(name = "PRENOM")
    private String prenom;

    @Column(name = "TYPE_PERSONNE")
    private TypeEmploye typePersonne;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="referent")
    private Set<AbstractClientEntity> listeClients;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employe", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<RoleEntity> authorities = new HashSet<RoleEntity>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="employe")
    private Set<ReunionEntity> reunions = new TreeSet<ReunionEntity>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private AbstractEmployeEntity responsable;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "DERNIER_LOGIN")
    private Date dernierLogin;

getter and setter....
}
```

Here is the way I try to do the specific mapping:

```
mapper.map(empl, AbstractEmployeDto.class, "employe_simple")
```

In this statement as soon as my employee has the collection `reunions` not empty, Hibernate throws a Lazy Loading exception...

I want to keep the lazy loading on the collections because I don't need them in the method. That's why I use a specific mapping to not map them.

Comment: What are the getters and setters for those fields, specifically?

Comment: They are standards:

    public Set<ReunionEntity> getReunions() {
      return reunions;
    }

    public void setReunions(Set<ReunionEntity> reunions) {
      this.reunions = reunions;
    }

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes, but I really can't remember what I was doing wrong... Sorry...